# How do I query a datetime where I wanted to show only AM?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Given the ff datetime

> ID1- 2015-01-15 11:15:23
>
> ID2- 2015-01-15 12:15:23
>
> ID3- 2015-01-15 13:15:23

How should I do the query to get AM only. For this one, I want to get ID1 only.

Comment: Why you expect not also ID3?

Comment: @jameslem if ID3 was PM it would be 13:15:23

Comment: @Bobby oh.. thanks for clearing that.. I haven't notice that

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where hour(datetime_column) between 0 and 11
```

Comment: Your query return ID1 and ID3. OP expectation is only ID1

Comment: I had tried that one but it includes other dates in my table.

Comment: What other dates and why should they not be returned?

Comment: @juergend I needed to query everyday transaction and separate them by date, but only the morning transaction. if the day is 2015-01-28, only morning transaction will be selected, on the next sheet 2015-01-29 still morning transaction.

Comment: That is what my query does. Or when it the morning transaction - between what time? Is it not between midnight and noon?